# How to Sync data between two devices using Core Data & iCloud?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

What I am trying to achieve is when user creates, changes or deletes data on the `persistent store` it will be synced with the `iCloud store` and then update other devices logged into the same iCloud account.

I have created a `Core Data Stack` using Objective-C resources and tried to write my own in Swift but I am having problems syncing the data using two devices logged into the same iCloud account.

For e.g. when **iDevice A** is logged into iCloud it will back up data to iCloud but when **iDevice B** logs into iCloud the app deletes any data already on the persistent storage to save the iCloud back up, and any changes between the store devices does not appear on the other but seem to save to the iCloud store as the latest back up, so if the app is deleted and reinstalled I see the latest backup made by the other device - with this in mind, if **iDevice B** was already logged in, it would not use data from **iDevice A** unless the app was reinstalled and the last back up was made by the other device.

Does anybody know where I am going wrong in the `Core data stack` to sync the data between two devices using the same iCloud account ?

**Core Data Stack:**

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack
// All the following code is in my appDelgate Core data stack 

func observeCloudActions(persistentStoreCoordinator psc:      NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?) {
// Register iCloud notifications observers for;

//Stores Will change 
//Stores Did Change 
//persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges
//mergeChanges

}

//Functions for notifications

func mergeChanges(notification: NSNotification) {
NSLog("mergeChanges notif:\(notification)")
if let moc = managedObjectContext {
    moc.performBlock {
        moc.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
        self.postRefetchDatabaseNotification()
    }
 }
}

  func persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges(notification: NSNotification) {
self.mergeChanges(notification);
 }    

func storesWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
NSLog("storesWillChange notif:\(notification)");
if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
    moc.performBlockAndWait {
        var error: NSError? = nil;
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            NSLog("Save error: \(error)");
        } else {
            // drop any managed objects
        }
        moc.reset();
    }

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("storeWillChange", object: nil)

 }
}

 func storesDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
NSLog("storesDidChange posting notif");
self.postRefetchDatabaseNotification();
//Sends notification to view controllers to reload data      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("storeDidChange", object: nil)

 }

func postRefetchDatabaseNotification() {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
          NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("storeDidChange", object: nil)

 })
 }


// Core data stack 

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
// The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "hyouuu.pendo" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
// The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("AppName", withExtension: "momd")!
NSLog("modelURL:\(modelURL)")
return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
// The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
// Create the coordinator and store
var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)


let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).last as! NSURL


let storeURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreData.sqlite")

NSLog("storeURL:\(storeURL)")

let storeOptions = [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:"AppStore"]

var error: NSError? = nil
var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(
    NSSQLiteStoreType,
    configuration: nil,
    URL: storeURL,
    options: storeOptions,
    error: &error) == nil
{
    coordinator = nil
    // Report any error we got.
    let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
    dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
    dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
    error = NSError(domain: "Pendo_Error_Domain", code: 9999, userInfo: dict as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog("AddPersistentStore error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
}

self.observeCloudActions(persistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator)

return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
// Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
if coordinator == nil {
    return nil
}
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Comment: I would suggest you try downloading the sample apps below and see if you can get them to work - if you have any issues let me know and I will help you.  Once you have them working you can try and figure out what you have done differently and update accordingly - there are many things that can cause you problems.  Remember to start with the early versions to avoid too much complexity in the beginning.
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Thanks for the resource, I have been going through the various project files and studying your work - you have done a great job !! The best resource available, Apple haven't assisted new developers. I have downloaded the "CoreDataStackManager.swift" file but unsure how to use it in my project, I have a new core data app for swift 2.0 to test your code. Should I replace my core data stack with the file core or create instances to use the functions ? (I am a new iOS developer)

Comment: I have started a repository for a pure Swift version of the sample apps here https://github.com/duncangroenewald/Core-Data-Sample-App.

Answer (score 2):

This how I have mine setup and it syncs my core data and it keeps changes synced.

[image]

This from my AppDelegate.

```
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("APPNAME.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    // iCloud store
    var storeOptions = [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : "APPNAMEStore",NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    // iCloud storeOptions need to be added to the if statement
    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(url.path!), options: storeOptions)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

    // MARK: - iCloud
// This handles the updates to the data via iCLoud updates

func registerCoordinatorForStoreNotifications (coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator) {
    let nc : NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter();

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoresWillChange:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification,
        object: coordinator)

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoresDidChange:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification,
        object: coordinator)

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoresWillRemove:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorWillRemoveStoreNotification,
        object: coordinator)

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoreChangedUbiquitousContent:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification,
        object: coordinator)
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, nice that it's in Swift 2 !! But working with Swift 1.1 atm, and still working on converting my code (150+ errors) where do you call your funcion to register notifications ?

Comment: Is your app in the App Store and you are having these issues?  If not I would strongly suggest moving to Swift 2 now. As you are going have to start all over on fixing some things again.  The code I have provide is all you need to get the core data to sync. Xcode 7/Swift 2 and iOS 9 will be released in less than a week.

Comment: You are right, I have starting converting my project and no I am planning to launch the app when iOS9 launches - that is if I everything with iCloud goes well. When you say sync, if I delete data on one device does it delete on the other as they should be using get same cloud persistent store ? Also where do you call the function for notifications ?

Comment: Yes if add one it shows on the other and vs if you delete it removes from the other.

Comment: I have created my functions for WillChange, DidChange and handleStoreChanges, but what is the WillRemove Notification ?? I cannot find an example using Apples Documentation

Comment: @JKSDEV Found this code that might help. [Try Looking at this](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/swift-code/)  also watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xwvdn9zVHWE)

Answer (score 1):

A difference I see between what works for me and your code is:

1)  I don't see where you've added an observer for the NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification such as in the code:

```
let nc : NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter();
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
nc.addObserver(self, selector: "dataUpdated:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification,
        object: self.managedObjectContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator)
```

2)  In my code in the function that catches the notification (dataUpdated in this case), it resets the managed objext context with the following code before it updates the display to show the new data:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
     managedObjectContext.reset()
}
```

After resetting the managed object context, I fetch the entity again using the code:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ClassNameHere")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [ClassNameHere]
```

Comment: Who's code are your referring to when you so say your code?

Comment: I'm referring to JKSDEV's code.  Your (MwcsMac's) example code does include the registration for notifications.  The problem I think is most likely that the data needs to be reset, re-fetched, and the display updated.